# Regex lookbehind/lookahead in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

Here is what i want to do:
I want to replace certain tokens in a string, but only if they are not inside another word.
Example:

```
  token= pos
  replacement= XXX
//Strings to check:
  Repository
  pos
  boss && pos
  boss && xpos && pos

//Expected results:
  Repository
  XXX
  boss && XXX
  boss && xpos && XXX
```

For that I created a regex:

```
/(?<!\w)POS(?!\w)/
```

The Problem is that POS should be a variable.
Since this only works with the new Regexp Syntax i tried to modify it like this:

```
var rx = new RegExp("(?<!\\w)" + item[0] + "(?!\\w)");
```

As you might guessed, in the end there is a loop that should replace several tokens in a string (/g is not needed).
The problem is, if I try to rund this codesegement above I always get an expection:

```
RuntimeException - org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier ?
```

Now I'm not sure if the problem is a faulty regex or if it simply is a limitation of nashorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace `pos` only as a standalone word, just use word boundaries:

```
var rx = new RegExp("\\b" + item[0] + "\\b");
```

Comment: omg, i did not know this command even exists, altough it would have been more strange if it didn't. Well thank you so much